# Trying to upload with ftplib, can connect just fine, but I'm messing something up at some point.

Tags: python

Here's the code that I have, it references a class that is not shown. The class_connector simply provides a template to collect connection credentials.

```
import connect_class
from ftplib import FTP
import os

account = connect_class.connector(raw_input('enter your hostname: '),
                          raw_input('enter your user name: '),
                          raw_input('enter your password: '),
                          raw_input('enter your directory: '))


ftp = FTP(account.host)
ftp.login(user=account.user, passwd=account.password)
ftp.retrlines('LIST')

def upload(ftp, file):
    ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    if ext in (".txt", ".htm", ".html"):
        ftp.storlines("STOR " + file, open(file))
    else:
        ftp.storbinary("STOR " + file, open(file, "rb"), 1024)

upload(ftp, '/file/somefile/file')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in a full path. You probably want to use the basename as the remote file name.

```
basename = os.path.basename(file)
if ext in (".txt", ".htm", ".html"):
    ftp.storlines("STOR " + basename, open(file))
else:
    ftp.storbinary("STOR " + basename, open(file, "rb"), 1024)
```